# Cannot successfully start WAR file on server

Tags: tomcat, grails

I've got a successfully compiled project which I want to run on a server.
Its a grails project and I tried to run it on a server

Here is the error from tomcat:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/brWXH.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqxs0.png

Catalinga.log:

```
2-apr-2014 14:43:45 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.27 using APR version 1.4.6.
2-apr-2014 14:43:45 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
2-apr-2014 14:43:46 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized with version OpenSSL 1.0.1d 5 Feb 2013
2-apr-2014 14:43:46 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
2-apr-2014 14:43:46 org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
2-apr-2014 14:43:46 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1158 ms
2-apr-2014 14:43:46 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
2-apr-2014 14:43:46 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.39
2-apr-2014 14:43:46 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
2-apr-2014 14:43:46 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
2-apr-2014 14:43:46 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive bba.war
2-apr-2014 14:44:15 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
2-apr-2014 14:44:15 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/bba] startup failed due to previous errors
2-apr-2014 14:44:18 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
2-apr-2014 14:44:18 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
2-apr-2014 14:44:18 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
2-apr-2014 14:44:19 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
2-apr-2014 14:44:19 org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
2-apr-2014 14:44:19 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 32751 ms
2-apr-2014 14:44:49 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
2-apr-2014 14:44:49 org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
2-apr-2014 14:44:50 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
2-apr-2014 14:44:51 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
2-apr-2014 14:44:51 org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
```

Localhost log:

```
2-apr-2014 14:43:48 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2-apr-2014 14:44:18 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
2-apr-2014 14:44:18 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
2-apr-2014 14:44:51 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
2-apr-2014 14:44:51 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
```

And the stacktrace.log is empty.
How to fix it?

Comment: Just a wild guess since I can't see the entire stacktrace (try posting the contents of catalina.out from the logs) but you might want to verify your datasource configuration.

Comment: Your server actually started.

Comment: hmm I can't find any error

Comment: You need to do a better job at asking your question.  Currently, there is no way to determine what your problem is.

Comment: Typically when you see those "SEVERE" startup errors in Tomcat you need to look at the `localhost.2014-04-01.log` file to see the real problem. Also see if there's anything helpful in `stacktrace.log`